# Is 2h+shield still viable for crusaders in 2.1?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-crusader

With the change to -20% damage with 2h+shield to crusaders, I know they upped the amount of damage 2h do so there should theoretically be slightly more damage than before,  but it just feels wrong to me.

Is the 2h+shield build still the way to go? Is 1h+shield viable now? Is dual wielding a good option now? What is the general consensus?

Comment: Crusaders can't dual wield, so that option is definitely out.

Comment: A lot of it just comes down to what equipment you find.  In general, I imagine (but can't confirm) that 2H+shield will be better simply because 2H in general have higher damage.

Comment: The new 2H damage can be as high as 4200. Considering that each 10% removes roughly 200 listed damage from a weapon, that still means the 2H is essentially capped at 3800. This is far higher than what 1H damage can reach, which is basically 2800.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**In short, yes, 2H+Shield is still viable, and is in fact better now.**

As Adesse pointed out, crusaders cannot dual wield, so you are stuck with a weapon+shield set. That being said, it is true that now using a 2H weapon with a shield causes a -20% penalty, but even before the patch the damage of a 2H weapon would have compensated for the penalty, meaning that 2H+Shield would have still been a (slight) improvement.

Now, with a buff to 2H weapons across the board, the net result is that 2H+Shield crusaders do slightly more damage than before the patch.